# Python. Нужно чтобы программа находила текст в текстовом документе, потом проверяла второй вводимый текст на нахождение в этой строке

Tags: python-3.6

Нужно чтобы программа находила данные переменной email в текстовом документе, потом проверяла данные переменной password на совпадение с текстом на этой строке. Всего в текстовом документе записаны email и password, на каждой строчке форматом:

email : password

email : password

Мне нужно дописать функцию, которая будет cверять password на этой строке с введённым password.

```
email = input('Введите ваш e-mail: ')
file = open(r"C:\\Users\\smirn\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\python\\MAINbase.txt", "r")
if file.read().find(email) != - 1:
    password = input ('Введите пароль: ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
email = input('Введите ваш e-mail: ')
password = input('Введите пароль: ')

with open(r"C:\\Users\\smirn\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Python\\python\\MAINbase.txt") as file:
    pairs = ([w.strip() for w in line.split(':', maxsplit=1)] for line in file)

    if [email, password] in pairs:
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('fail')
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю создать словарь на основе файла, так Вы сможете использовать базу неоднократно:

```py
base = {}
with open('base.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        email, password = row.strip().split(' : ')
        base[email] = password

email = input('Введите ваш e-mail: ')
password = input('Введите ваш пароль: ')

if base.get(email) and base[email] == password:
    print('Правильный пароль')
else:
    print('Неправильный пароль')
```